# Why is Mongoose deleting the top most item in my database, rather than the id matching the target item?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

Sorry with the constant questions folks, but this one I can't quite get.

I have a button that activates the /post command below to delete an item via Mongoose. However, I'm finding that it is ignoring the :id that is attached.

The console.log displays the correct id to delete the target entry, the id variable also displays the correct id that is being targeted, but the entry that gets deleted seems to be the top most entry in my list, rather than the target id.

Is there something obvious I'm not seeing below that might cause this? server.js /post below:

```
app.post('/remove/team/:id', (req, res) => {
    console.log("Delete command received. " + req.params.id)
  var id = req.params.id;
  if(!ObjectID.isValid(id)) {
    return res.status(404).send();
  }
  Team.findOneAndRemove(id).then((team) => {
    if(!team) {
      return res.status(404).send();
    }
    res.render("deleteSuccess.hbs", {id});
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  });
});
```

As always, any help offered is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: do you have multiple docs with the same id? if yes, have you tried passing *sort* in options?

Comment: No, the ID's are unique, generated by MongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run this query:-

```
Team.findOneAndRemove({ _id: id })
  .then()
  .catch()
```

findOneAndRemove takes a condition as first param and not just id.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for the solve, that worked perfectly. Appreciate the answer.